# How to make a responsive grid where margins decrease as grid content stays the same?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a grid similar to this one:

https://masteroverwatch.com/streams/sort/skillrating

where the margins around the grid become narrower and the grid stays the same width and aspect ratio until it absolutely has to become smaller via a break point.

any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `margin: 0 auto;`.

Here's a simple example:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  background: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="box"></div></div>
```